# getCommand(String) return null value

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm new in minecraft plugins development and I have a problem than i can't solve.

I try to response to the sender when he write /point in the chat. I have this in my first class:

```
package fr.azmog25.pointsaver.pointsaver;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class PointSaver extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        System.out.println("Serveur lancé !");
        System.out.println(this.getCommand("point"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
        System.out.println("Serveur éteint !");
    }
}
```

My second class look's like this :

```
package fr.azmog25.pointsaver.pointsaver;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class PointAdder implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        System.out.println("Vous devez être un joueur !");
        return false;
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;
    player.sendMessage("bravo ça marche !");
    return true;
}
```

}

and my plugin.yml have :

```
name: PointSaver
version: 1.0
main: fr.azmog25.pointsaver.pointsaver.PointSaver
commands:
  point:
    description: Save coordinates
    permission: point.use
```

But the `getCommand()` always return null and it's my first time in plugin development...

Comment: Have you registered the yaml file?

Comment: Are you talking about the plugin.yml ?

Comment: Yes. Be sure it's the right one which is used. Also, don't use `System.out.println`, prefer use `sender.sendMessage`

Comment: Yes but where i need to put my plugin.yml ? I'm using ouiheberg and i don't know where i need to put the yml files. In the main repository or with the .jar file ?
And how can i see which yml file he's using ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the command in your onEnable() method.

Remove **System.out.println(this.getCommand("point");** and add the below code into your onEnable() method.

```
this.getCommand("point").setExecutor(new PointAdder());
```

That should hopefully fix the issue. I would also take the other answers' advice and make sure your plugin.yml is in the right spot.

Comment: What is the right spot for `plugin.yml` ?

Answer (score -1):

Don't you need to add an executor to your command to make it return something ?
this.getCommand("point").setExecutor(new PointAdder());

It should probably fix your stuff.

(+ According to your last comment the plugin.yml file should be at the root of your jar file.)

Comment: he can't invoke setExecutor() from getCommand because getCommand returns null